# Using embedded value objects in spring data jpa projections

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I'm working with Spring Boot 2.0RC2 and in the documentation I read you can return a projection of an entity instead of the entity as a whole when calling the Repository. This is working fine in case I use a String in my Entity but not when I use an embedded value objects.

Let's say I have the `Product` entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_product")
public class Product extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    private Product() {}

    private Product(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static Result<Product> create(@NonNull final String name) {
        return Result.ok(new Product(name));
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(@NonNull final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

The `BaseEntity` simply holds the `id`, `created` and `updated` attributes.

I have my projection interface called `ProductSummary`:

```
interface ProductSummary {
    String getName();
    Long getNameLength();
}
```

And in my `ProductRepository` I have the following method that returns the `ProductSummary`:

```
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT p.name as name, LENGTH(p.name) as nameLength FROM Product p WHERE p.id = :id")
    ProductSummary findSummaryById(@Param("id") Long id);
}
```

This works perfectly fine. Now let's say I am doing DDD and instead of using a String to represent the `name` attribute in the `Product` entity, I want to use a value object called `Name`:

```
@Embeddable
public class Name implements Serializable {

    public static final int MAX_NAME_LENGTH = 100;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = Name.MAX_NAME_LENGTH)
    private String value;

    private Name() {}

    private Name(final String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static Result<Name> create(@NonNull final String name) {
        if (name.isEmpty()) {
            return Result.fail("Name cannot be empty");
        }

        if (name.length() > MAX_NAME_LENGTH) {
            return Result.fail("Name cannot be longer than " + MAX_NAME_LENGTH + " characters");
        }

        return Result.ok(new Name(name));
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

I change my `Product` entity to:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_product")
public class Product extends BaseEntity {

    @Embedded
    private Name name;

    private Product() {}

    private Product(final Name name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static Result<Product> create(@NonNull final Name name) {
        return Result.ok(new Product(name));
    }

    public Name getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(final Name name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

And in the `ProductSummary` I change the return type from `String` to `Name`.

When I run that I always get the exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class com.acme.core.product.ProductSummary from class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy112
```

Can I make this work or am I missing some restriction which doesn't allow this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to get the complete Name field(not a particular field in Name class), then you need to create another interface like ProductSummary.

```
interface ProductSummary {
    NameSummary getName();

    interface NameSummary {
      String getValue();
    }
}
```

No need to change anything in your repository.

It is quite clearly documented [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections)

**And make sure your interfaces  and the methods are public.**

Comment: I actually tried that but still no dice, can it have anything to do with the fact that I'm using a custom query?

Comment: It has nothing to do with Custom Query, Have you set the return types and Method names in the interfaces correctly?

Comment: as far as I can tell, I took your code, removed the `String getName()` and left the `NameSummary getName()` and added the new interface. The rest of the code is exactly as I posted above. Everything works when I use `String` type for the name and it gives me the exception when I do a type migration to `Name` (even with the added `NameSummary`)

Comment: the same exception ?

Comment: Yep, same exception unfortunately

Comment: is ProductSummary and NameSummary public?

Comment: I had a look at the spring-data-jpa samples and found [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-data-jpa/src/main/java/sample/data/jpa/service/HotelRepository.java) where they also use a custom query and a `HotelSummary`, if you navigate up the directory you'll see that in their `HotelSummary` interface they don't use a separate `CitySummary` but simply return the `City` object itself so that's why I didn't include it in my example (but I had tried it before)

Comment: Yes that is true. If you want the whole nested object you can do without the need for another interface. But if you want any particular field only in the nested object then you need to create interface

Comment: Oh boy, that's embarrassing, it was package-private, once set to public it works of course. Thanks for assisting :P

Comment: ha ha. Ya it happens. IllegalAccessError is the clue. Hence I asked. Anyways, Do accept the answer. Il edit and include this in the answer